# Como upar muitos arquivos via postman ? API GOLANG [RESOLVIDO]

Tags: golang, postman

Estou com duvida em relação a como upar muitos arquivos de uma vez no form-data do postman.
eu consigo upar 1 arquivo por vez, mas não consigo upar mais de 1 por vez
Codigo:

Estou com duvida em relação a como upar muitos arquivos de uma vez no form-data do postman.
eu consigo upar 1 arquivo por vez, mas não consigo upar mais de 1 por vez
Codigo:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "mime/multipart"
    "net/http"
    "path/filepath"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

type BindFile struct {
    Name  string                `form:"name" binding:"required"`
    Email string                `form:"email" binding:"required"`
    File  *multipart.FileHeader `form:"file" binding:"required"`
}

func main() {
    router := gin.Default()

    router.POST("/upload", func(c *gin.Context) {
        var bindFile BindFile

        c.ShouldBind(&bindFile)
        file := bindFile.File
        dst := filepath.Base(file.Filename)
        c.SaveUploadedFile(file, dst)

        c.String(http.StatusOK, fmt.Sprintf("arquivo %s upado com sucesso", file.Filename))
    })

    router.Run(":8080")
}
```

Comment: você já tentou usar `File` como um `slice`? exemplo: `File []*multipart.FileHeader`

Comment: tentei, porem ele resulta em alguns erros na variavel dst e SaveUploadFile

Comment: coloca na pergunta o exemplo usando o `slice` por favor

Answer (score -2):

CONSEGUI RESOLVER DA SEGUINTE FORMA:

```html
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "path/filepath"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
    router := gin.Default()

    router.POST("/", func(c *gin.Context) {

        form, _ := c.MultipartForm()

        files := form.File["files"]

        for _, file := range files {
            filename := filepath.Base(file.Filename)
            if err := c.SaveUploadedFile(file, filename); err != nil {
                c.String(http.StatusBadRequest, "erro ao carregar arquivo")
            }
        }
        c.String(http.StatusOK, "upload realizado, %d files ", len(files))
    })
    router.Run(":8080")
}
```

fonte: https://github.com/gin-gonic/examples/blob/master/upload-file/multiple/main.go
nao tratei os erros e o codigo esta muito simples